# Why does mod_rewrite ignore my [L] flag?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, redirect, web-applications, assets

This is my `.htaccess` file. It should deliver static files from `assets` folder if the url matches them. Otherwise, everything should be redirected to `index.php`.

Note that the url doesn't contain `assets` as segemnt here. So `example.com/css/style.css` directs to `assets/css/style.css`.

```
RewriteEngine on

# disable directory browsing
Options -Indexes

# static assets
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/assets/$1 -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ assets/$1 [L]

# other requests to index.php
RewriteRule !^asset/ index.php [L]
```

Unfortunately, urls like `example.com/assets/css/style.css` also deliver the file, since for that url none of my rules applies and Apache's default behavior is applied which delivers the file.

So I tried changing the last line to this. I thought that this would work since the `[L]` flag in the rule above should stop execution for asset urls and deliver them.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L]
```

Instead, not all requests are redirected to `index.php`, even static assets like `example.com/css/style.css`. Why does the flag not stop execution of rewrite rules and who to fix my problem then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution on the pages of the [official documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_l).

> If you are using RewriteRule in either .htaccess files or in
>    sections, it is important to have some understanding of
>   how the rules are processed. The simplified form of this is that once
>   the rules have been processed, the rewritten request is handed back to
>   the URL parsing engine to do what it may with it. It is possible that
>   as the rewritten request is handled, the .htaccess file or 
>   section may be encountered again, and thus the ruleset may be run
>   again from the start. Most commonly this will happen if one of the
>   rules causes a redirect - either internal or external - causing the
>   request process to start over.
>
> It is therefore important, if you are using RewriteRule directives in
>   one of these contexts, that you take explicit steps to avoid rules
>   looping, and not count solely on the [L] flag to terminate execution
>   of a series of rules, as shown below.
>
> An alternative flag, [END], can be used to terminate not only the
>   current round of rewrite processing but prevent any subsequent rewrite
>   processing from occurring in per-directory (htaccess) context. This
>   does not apply to new requests resulting from external redirects.

To fix my problem, I changed to `[L]` flags to `[END]`.

```
RewriteEngine on

# disable directory browsing
Options -Indexes

# static assets
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/assets/$1 -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ assets/$1 [END]

# other requests to index.php
RewriteRule !^asset/ index.php [END]
```