# Why is apache changing the browser's url even when I have an [L] mod rewrite rule?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, mediawiki

Why is apache ignoring my [L] flag? I would expect to go to myhost.com/wtf and be taken to myhost.com/mediawiki/index.php *without* the URL in the browser changing. The problem is that the browser url IS changing, and its maddeningly frustrating.

Here's my simple test rule:

`RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/wtf.*$ /mediawiki/index.php [L]`

I've ensured that there are no .htaccess files in www, www/html, or www/html/mediawiki. I've tried using the [END] flag as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20594828/why-does-mod-rewrite-ignore-my-l-flag). I don't have any other rewrite rules in httpd.conf. What could be going wrong?

PS. I curse whoever wrote apache to the depths of hell.

Comment: I agree with you - the rule tells the server to perform an internal rewrite _without_ external redirection. At a guess, there _must_ be some additional interference from elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're omitting the rest of your Apache config or, more likely, the wiki is trying to ensure a canonical URL which isn't configured to the one you want.

Comment: Ah you were right. I had misconfigured my $wgArticlePath in LocalSettings.php . But man, this shouldn't be so difficult. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to help but URL configuration is pretty standard fare for web apps.